# How to improve the performance of my app in flutter

Tags: json, performance, flutter, dart

I am building an app called LiveTv which is an app which recommends videos as per varied interests.The code I have written is causing serious lags and as I am proceeding more and more in this app it is becoming next to inoperable.I have included the video of the same in this link https://youtu.be/YQp3E3Lukfk

What I have done is make the call async and I have used a ternary operator wherein which under it loads a circular progress indicator is shown.But it doesn't seems to work only

I have included the code which is the one which is controlled by the bottom navigation bar.The services part of it is not included as its function is only to load the data or the object,but I will include one or two so that you may understand and I dont want to make this question very long

```
class LiveTvHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  final String title;

  LiveTvHomePage({
    this.title,
  });

  @override
  _LiveTvHomePageState createState() => _LiveTvHomePageState();
}

class _LiveTvHomePageState extends State<LiveTvHomePage> {
//GlobalKey<ScaffoldState> _drawerKey = GlobalKey<ScaffoldState>();
 

  @override
  void initState() {
    // TODO: implement initState
    super.initState();
    handleScroll(); // function which is responsible for updating the isScrollingDown variable whenever the user scrolls down
    _services();
    setState(() {
      _isLoading = false;
    });
  }

  _loadingImage() {
    return CircularProgressIndicator();
  }

  _services() {
    Services.loadDataForMovieId().then((movieIdList) {
      setState(() {
        _homeBannerObjectMovieIdList = movieIdList;
      });
    });

    Services.loadDataForMovieIdofPopularMovieSection().then((movieIdList) {
      setState(() {
        _popularMoviesMovieId = movieIdList;
      });
    });
    Services.loadDataForPopularTvShowSection().then((homePageSeriesPosterList) {
      setState(() {
        _seriesData = homePageSeriesPosterList;
      });
    });

    Services.loadDataForMusicSection().then((musicList) {
      setState(() {
        _musicCategories = musicList;
      });
    });

    Services.loadDataForPlaylistTitle().then((title) {
      setState(() {
        _musicPlaylistThemeName = title;
      });
    });

    Services.loadDataForPopularNewsChannelsNames().then((nameList) {
      setState(() {
        _popularNewsChannelNames = nameList;
      });
    });

    Services.loadDataForPopularNewsChannelsProfilePicUrls().then((urllist) {
      setState(() {
        _popularNewsChannelProfilePicUrl = urllist;
      });
    });
    Services.loadDataForLiveNewsChannelsProfilePicUrls().then((urllist) {
      setState(() {
        _liveNewsChannelProfilePicUrl = urllist;
      });
    });
    Services.loadDataForLiveNewsChannelsNames().then((nameList) {
      setState(() {
        _liveNewsChannelNames = nameList;
      });
    });
    Services.loadDataForPicOfLatestNews().then((nameList) {
      setState(() {
        _latestNewsProfilePics = nameList;
      });
    });
    Services.loadDataForOfLatestNewsTitle().then((nameList) {
      setState(() {
        _latestNewsNewsTitle = nameList;
      });
    });
    Services.loadDataForOfLatestNewsDescription().then((nameList) {
      setState(() {
        _latestNewsDescription = nameList;
      });
    });
  }

  _buildBody(var boxHeight, List<String> youtubeIdUrls) {
    return Column(
      children: <Widget>[
        Stack(
          children: <Widget>[
            _buildPageView(boxHeight, youtubeIdUrls),
            _buildCircleIndicator(youtubeIdUrls),
          ],
        ),
      ],
    );
  }

  _buildPageView(var boxHeight, List<String> youtubeIdUrls) {
    return Container(
      color: Colors.black87,
      height: boxHeight,
      child: PageView.builder(
          itemCount: 8,
          controller: _pageController,
          itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
            try {
              // HomeBanner homeBanner=_homeBannelList[index];
              return FadeInImage.assetNetwork(
                image:
                    'https://img.youtube.com/vi/${youtubeIdUrls[index].substring(8)}/0.jpg',
                placeholder: 'assets/loading.gif',
                fit: BoxFit.fill,
              );
            } catch (e) {
              return CircularProgressIndicator();
            }
            //before return Image.network('https://img.youtube.com/vi/${videoIdOfUrlList[index]}/0.jpg',fit: BoxFit.fill,);
          },
          onPageChanged: (int index) {
            _currentPageNotifier.value = index;
          }),
    );
  }

  _buildCircleIndicator(List<String> youtubeIdUrls) {
    return Positioned(
      left: 0.0,
      right: 0.0,
      bottom: 0.0,
      child: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
        child: CirclePageIndicator(
          itemCount: 8,
          currentPageNotifier: _currentPageNotifier,
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget imageDisplayed(String picUrl) {
    return Row(
      children: <Widget>[
        const SizedBox(
          width: 10,
        ),
        CircleAvatar(
          backgroundImage: NetworkImage(picUrl),
          radius: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.08,
          backgroundColor: Colors.black,
        ),
        const SizedBox(
          width: 10,
        ),
      ],
    );
  }

  Widget HorizontalListViewWitCircularCards(
      String title, List<String> urlList, List<String> nameList) {
    return Container(
      color: Colors.black,
      height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.32,
      width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
      child: Column(
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
        children: <Widget>[
          Container(
            height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.07,
            color: Colors.black,
            alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
            child: Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(10, 0, 0, 0),
              child: Text(
                title,
                style: TextStyle(fontSize: 16, color: Colors.white),
              ),
            ),
          ),
          Container(
            height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.23,
            child: ListView.builder(
              shrinkWrap: true,
              scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
              itemCount: _popularNewsChannelNames.length,
              itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) => Card(
                color: Colors.black,
                child: Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(),
                  child: Column(
                    children: <Widget>[
                      imageDisplayed(urlList[index]),
                      const SizedBox(
                        height: 13,
                      ),
                      Text(
                        nameList[index],
                        style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget HorizontalGridViewOfCardsofGradientColor(int count, List<String> lst) {
    return Container(
      color: Colors.black,
      height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.125 * count,
      child: GridView.count(
        scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
        crossAxisCount: count,
        shrinkWrap: true,
        mainAxisSpacing: 10,
        crossAxisSpacing: 10,
        children: List.generate(20, (index) {
          return Container(
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
              border: Border.all(
                color: Colors.black,
              ),
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(15)),
              gradient: LinearGradient(colors: colorsForCardinMusicPage[index]),
            ),
            child: Center(
              child: Text(
                lst[index],
              ),
            ),
          );
        }),
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget HorizontalGridViewOfCardsofGradientColorWithtitle(
      int count, String title) {
    return Column(
      
    );
  }



  Widget HorizontalListViewOfButtons(List moviesPageButtonNames) {
    return Container(
      color: Colors.black,
      height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.13,
      child: ListView.builder(
        shrinkWrap: true,
        scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
        itemCount: moviesPageButtonNames.length,
        itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) => Row(
          children: <Widget>[
            SizedBox(
              width: 7,
            ),
            FlatButton(
              shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(18.0),
                  side: BorderSide(color: Colors.grey)),
              color: Colors.grey[800],
              textColor: Colors.white,
              onPressed: () {},
              child: Text(moviesPageButtonNames[index]),
            ),
            SizedBox(
              width: 10,
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }


  Widget NewsPageOfBottomNavigator() {
    ServicesForNewsPage.loadObjectList().then((newsPageObject) {
      _newsPage = newsPageObject;
    });
    for (var obj in _newsPage.liveChannels) {
      _newsPageLiveNewsUrls.add(obj.publisherProfilePic);
      _newsPageChannelName.add(obj.publisherName);
    }
//    print("_newsPageLiveNewsUrls");
//    print(_newsPageLiveNewsUrls);
//    print("_newsPageLiveNewsNames");
//    print(_newsPageChannelName);`
    for (var obj in _newsPage.news) {
      _newsPagePopularNewsChannelUrls.add(obj.publishers.profilePicUrl);
      _newsPagePopularNewsChannelNames.add(obj.publishers.fullName);
    }
    return Column(
      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
      children: <Widget>[
        HorizontalListViewWithoutViewAllForLiveNewsChannels(
            "Watch Live", _newsPageLiveNewsUrls, _newsPageChannelName),
        HorizontalListViewWitCircularCards("Popular News Channel",
            _newsPagePopularNewsChannelUrls, _newsPagePopularNewsChannelNames),
        VerticalListView(_newsPagePopularNewsChannelNames, true),
      ],
    );
  }

  Widget LifeStylePageOfBottomNavigator() {
    return Column(
      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
      children: <Widget>[
        HorizontalListViewWitCircularCards(
            "Popular Lifestyle channels", [""], [""]),
        VerticalListView(["ssss"], false),
      ],
    );
  }

  Widget SportsPageOfBottomNavigator() {
    return Column(
      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
      children: <Widget>[
        HorizontalListViewWitCircularCards(
            "Popular Sports channels", [""], [""]),
        VerticalListView(["ssss"], false),
      ],
    );
  }

  Widget returnToTopButton() {
    return Visibility(
      visible: _showButton,
      child: FlatButton(
        child: Row(
          children: <Widget>[
            Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0, 7, 0, 0),
              child: Text(
                "^",
                style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 27),
              ),
            ),
            Text(
              "     Return to top",
              style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
            ),
          ],
        ),
        onPressed: () {
          _scrollController.animateTo(0,
              duration: Duration(milliseconds: 500), curve: Curves.easeInOut);
        },
        color: Colors.red,
      ),
    );
  }

  void showFloationButton() {
    setState(() {
      _showButton = true;
    });
  }

  void hideFloationButton() {
    setState(() {
      _showButton = false;
    });
  }

  void handleScroll() async {
    // or something else..

    _scrollController.addListener(() {
      double currentScroll = _scrollController.position.pixels;
      double delta = MediaQuery.of(context).size.height;
//      print("Current scroll position is ..........$currentScroll");
//      print("delta pixel is ..........$delta");

      if (currentScroll >= delta) {
        showFloationButton();
      } else if (currentScroll <= delta) {
        hideFloationButton();
      }
    });
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    // TODO: implement dispose
    _scrollController.removeListener(() {});
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    List<Widget> wdgs_option = [
      HomePageForBottomNavigator(),
      MoviesPageForBottomNavigator(),
      TvSHowsPageOfBottomNavigator(),
      MusicPageofBottomNavigator(),
      // NewsPageOfBottomNavigator(), //dummy for now
      NewsPageOfBottomNavigator(),
      LifeStylePageOfBottomNavigator(),
      SportsPageOfBottomNavigator()
    ];
    return _isLoading
        ? _loadingImage()
        : Scaffold(
            //   key: _drawerKey,
            appBar: AppBar(
              automaticallyImplyLeading: false,
              leading: Icon(
                Icons.live_tv,
                color: Colors.amber,
              ),
              backgroundColor: Colors.black,
              title: Text(
                widget.title,
                style: TextStyle(fontSize: 17, color: Colors.amber),
              ),
              actions: <Widget>[
                IconButton(
                  tooltip: 'Search',
                  icon: const Icon(Icons.search),
                  onPressed: () {},
                ),
                IconButton(
                  icon: Icon(
                    MaterialCommunityIcons.xbox_controller_menu,
                    color: Colors.white,
                  ),
                  onPressed: () {
                    Navigator.push(
                      context,
                      MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => DrawerWidget()),
                    );
                  },
                )
              ],
            ),
            body: SafeArea(
              child: SingleChildScrollView(
                controller: _scrollController,
                child: wdgs_option.elementAt(_selectedIndex),
              ),
            ),
            drawer: Drawer(),
            bottomNavigationBar: BottomNavigationBar(
              backgroundColor: Colors.black,
              showUnselectedLabels: true,
              type: BottomNavigationBarType.shifting,
              currentIndex: _selectedIndex,
              fixedColor: Colors.amber,
              onTap: _onItemTapped,
              items: const <BottomNavigationBarItem>[
//          Icon(
//            FontAwesome.facebook_square,
//            color: Colors.amber,
//          ),
                BottomNavigationBarItem(
                  backgroundColor: Colors.black,
                  icon: Icon(Icons.home),
                  title: Text('Home'),
                ),
                BottomNavigationBarItem(
                  backgroundColor: Colors.black,
                  icon: Icon(
                    MaterialCommunityIcons.video_vintage,
                  ),
                  title: Text(
                    'Movies',
                  ),
                ),
                BottomNavigationBarItem(
                  backgroundColor: Colors.black,
                  icon: Icon(Icons.live_tv),
                  title: Text(
                    'Tv shows',
                  ),
                ),

                BottomNavigationBarItem(
                  backgroundColor: Colors.black,
                  icon: Icon(Icons.music_video),
                  title: Text(
                    'Music',
                  ),
                ),
//          BottomNavigationBarItem(
//            backgroundColor: Colors.black,
//            icon: Icon(Icons.dehaze),
//            title: Text(
//              'More',
//            ),
//          ),

                BottomNavigationBarItem(
                  backgroundColor: Colors.black,
                  icon: Icon(Icons.radio),
                  title: Text(
                    'News',
                  ),
                ),
                BottomNavigationBarItem(
                  backgroundColor: Colors.black,
                  icon: Icon(
                    FontAwesome.heartbeat,
                  ),
                  title: Text(
                    'LifeStyle',
                  ),
                ),
                BottomNavigationBarItem(
                  backgroundColor: Colors.black,
                  icon: Icon(
                    Ionicons.md_football,
                  ),
                  title: Text(
                    'Sports',
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          );
  }
}
```

The services class seems like this in most cases:

```
class ServicesForNewsPage {
  static const String url =
      "https://livetvapi.apyhi.com/api/v3/home?pageLocation=News&countries=IN&app_version=13&"
      "user_id=44edc2c905ae163f&package_id=livetv.movies.freemovies.watchtv.tvshows&os_platform=android";

  static Future<NewsPage> loadObjectList() async {
    var res = await http
        .get(url, headers: {'Authorization': dartJsonWebTokenGenerator()});

    if (res.statusCode == 200) {
      // print("response is there for news Page");
      final newsPageObjectList = newsPageFromJson(res.body);

      return newsPageObjectList;
    } else {
      print("no response");
      return null;
    }
  }
}
```

I am quite new to flutter and things are bit hazy as to how to improve the response time.

Answer (score 1):

You're question is quite broad. Have you tried playing with the DevTools?

I don't know the full code of your project, but I think I see that you are initializing all pages every time the build() of your homepage is called.

Consider changing this:

```
    List<Widget> wdgs_option = [
      HomePageForBottomNavigator(),
      MoviesPageForBottomNavigator(),
      TvSHowsPageOfBottomNavigator(),
      MusicPageofBottomNavigator(),
      // NewsPageOfBottomNavigator(), //dummy for now
      NewsPageOfBottomNavigator(),
      LifeStylePageOfBottomNavigator(),
      SportsPageOfBottomNavigator()
    ];
```

to something either 1.:

```
    if (_selectedIndex == 0) {
      wdgs_option = HomePageForBottomNavigator();
    } else if (hi == _selectedIndex) {
      wdgs_option = MoviesPageForBottomNavigator();
    } else if (){}
```

or to 2.:

```
    List<int Function()> wdgs_option = [
      () => HomePageForBottomNavigator(),
      () => MoviesPageForBottomNavigator(),
      () => ...
    ];

    int val = c[1]();
```

and in that case

```
SingleChildScrollView(
  controller: _scrollController,
  child: wdgs_option.elementAt(_selectedIndex),
)
```

to

```
SingleChildScrollView(
  controller: _scrollController,
  child: wdgs_option[_selectedIndex](),
)
```

Comment: I have to say your answer did throw light on some issues which I am facing.I tried implemented whatever you told using if else by switch,but the first 3 index I am getting proper output.But the remaining ones I am getting                                          
           RangeError (index): Invalid value: Valid value range is empty: 0,also for every widget I load I get the same error

Comment: Without further code it will be difficult to debug. But an out of range error sounds like you haven't added these pages to the array?